# Handling different functions calls using New Input System

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity New Input System, I have recently migrated my project from the old input system to the new input system but I'm facing some difficulties using it.

I have a class called `InputManager` that manages all the input actions for my game, and another class called `PlayerInteractions` that holds all the player's interactions, such as picking up objects, opening and closing drawers/doors and so on.

`playerInteraction` class was working perfectly using the old input system, but when I changed it to the new input system I couldn't handle the function calls properly so it didn't work completely. I managed to make picking up objects work but the opening/closing part didn't work because for that I'm calling another function from a class called `InteractiveObjects` that is attached to all objects that can be opened/closed such as door/drawers...

and it was hard for me to handle these function calls since I'm not good enough at the New Input System.

Here is a snippet of the `PlayerInteractions Class`

```
private InteractiveObjects interactiveObjects;
    bool PickingUp, Open;
  void Update()
    {
        raycastPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
        {
            lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            lookObject=null;
        }

        if (PickingUp) 
        {
            if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
            {
                if (lookObject != null)
                {

                    PickupObject();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                BreakConnection();
            }
        }
        PickingUp = false;
        if (hit.transform)
        {
            interactiveObjects = hit.transform.GetComponent<InteractiveObjects>();
        }
        else
        {
            lookObject = null;
            interactiveObjects = null;
        }
        if (Open)
        {
            if (interactiveObjects)
            {               
                interactiveObjects.PerformAction();

            }
        }
        Open = false;
    }
    public void OnPickingUp() 
    {
        PickingUp = true;
    }
    public void OnOpen()
    {
        Open = true;
    }
```

This part from above:

```
 if (Open)
            {
                if (interactiveObjects)
                {               
                    interactiveObjects.PerformAction();
    
                }
            }
```

was like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (interactiveObjects)
            {
                interactiveObjects.PerformAction();
            }
        }
```

and the `InteractiveObject` class was something like this:

```
 public void PerformAction()
    {
        if (aSource) 
        {
            aSource.Play(); 
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (isOpen)
            {
                iTweenArgs["position"] = closedPosition;
                iTweenArgs["rotation"] = closedPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                iTweenArgs["position"] = openPosition;
                iTweenArgs["rotation"] = openPosition;
            }

            isOpen = !isOpen;


            switch(movementType)
            {
                case MovementType.Slide:
                    iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
                    break;
                case MovementType.Rotate:
                    iTween.RotateTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
                    break; 
            } 
        }
```

`if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` was changed to `if (Open)`.

Here is the full `IneractiveObject` class after the change:

```
 public class InteractiveObjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Vector3 openPosition, closedPosition;
    
        [SerializeField] private float animationTime;
    
        [SerializeField] private bool isOpen = false;
    
        [SerializeField] private MovementType movementType;
    
        bool Open; 
    private enum MovementType { Slide, Rotate };

    private Hashtable iTweenArgs;

    private AudioSource aSource;

   
    void Start()
    {
        iTweenArgs = iTween.Hash();
        iTweenArgs.Add("position", openPosition);
        iTweenArgs.Add("time", animationTime);
        iTweenArgs.Add("islocal", true);

        aSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        if (aSource)
        {
            aSource.Play();
        }
        
        if (Open)
        {
            if (isOpen)
            {
                iTweenArgs["position"] = closedPosition;
                iTweenArgs["rotation"] = closedPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                iTweenArgs["position"] = openPosition;
                iTweenArgs["rotation"] = openPosition;
            }

            isOpen = !isOpen;


            switch (movementType)
            {
                case MovementType.Slide:
                    iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
                    break;
                case MovementType.Rotate:
                    iTween.RotateTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
                    break;
            }
        }
        Open = false;
        

    }

    public void OnOpen()
    {
        
        Open = true;
    }

}
```

Here is my Input Action:
[image]

`InputManager` class:

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Movement movement;
    [SerializeField] PlayerInteractions playerInteractions;
    [SerializeField] MouseLook mouseLook;
    PlayerControls controls; 
    PlayerControls.GroundMovementActions groundMovement;
    Vector2 horizontalInput;
    Vector2 mouseInput;

    private void Awake() 
  {
        controls = new PlayerControls(); 
        groundMovement = controls.GroundMovement;
        // groundMovement.[action].performed += context => do something
        groundMovement.HorizontalMovement.performed += ctx => horizontalInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        groundMovement.Jump.performed += _ => movement.OnJumpPressed();
        groundMovement.Running.performed += _ => movement.OnRunning();
        groundMovement.PickingUp.performed += _ => playerInteractions.OnPickingUp();
        groundMovement.MouseX.performed += ctx => mouseInput.x = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        groundMovement.MouseY.performed += ctx => mouseInput.y = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        groundMovement.Open.performed += _ => playerInteractions.OnOpen(); 
     
    }   

    private void Update()
    {
        movement.ReceiveInput(horizontalInput);
        mouseLook.ReceiveInput(mouseInput); 
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable(); 
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        controls.Disable(); 
    }


}
```

So the `InputManager` class is calling a function from `playerInteractions` which is also calling a function from `InteractiveObjects` for opening/closing feature. that didn't work for me but I don't know how to fix this. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is here, you no longer need `Open` Boolean and you can call the function directly through the new input system. for this job; Enter only the contents of if on `OnOpen`.

```cs
public void OnOpen()
{
    if (isOpen)
    {
        iTweenArgs["position"] = closedPosition;
        iTweenArgs["rotation"] = closedPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        iTweenArgs["position"] = openPosition;
        iTweenArgs["rotation"] = openPosition;
    }

    isOpen = !isOpen;

    switch(movementType)
    {
        case MovementType.Slide:
            iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
            break;
        case MovementType.Rotate:
            iTween.RotateTo(gameObject, iTweenArgs);
            break; 
    } 
}
```

This not only simplifies the structure of the code. Rather, it prevents the if condition from being repeated in the update. Now run `OnOpen` as you set it by pressing the <kbd>B</kbd> key:

```cs
controls.GroundMovement.Open.performed += _ => playerInteraction.OnOpen();
```

---

### How do conditions work continuously?

There are several ways to build functions that work continuously. This is an example that works by defining `Func<bool>` in the target object script:

```cs
public class PlayerInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Func<bool> IsPressingOpen;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (IsPressingOpen())
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

And it is enough to set the function according to the result of `key pressing`:

```cs
playerInteraction.IsPressingOpen = () => controls.GroundMovement.Open.IsPressed();
```

Hope this answer is comprehensive and practical.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. so on the first part of the answer, I got that I need to change the function name in the InteractiveObject class to OnOpen(), then in the InputManager class the function was called from PlayerInteractions class like so: controls.GroundMovement.Open.performed += _ => playerInteraction.OnOpen(); but you didn't mention how to call the function from playerInteraction.

Comment: I tried the sconed part of the answer too, IsPressed(); is not defined. and it causes errors.

Comment: @Okashi May I ask, do you generally receive a callback when you press the keys or does any key not work when you press it?

Comment: Yes, generally all of the actions in the Input Action work, except for Open.

Comment: I think the problem is that it never makes it to the function in InteractiveObject from PLayerInteractions. I tried printing a line in there but it never prints, so it didn't reach to the function properly I think.

Comment: email me your codes on (Kian.tianxuan@gmail.com) if your problem doesn't solve.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so helpful. I will try a little more to make it work, if it didn't I will send you. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you it finally worked. The issue wasn't in the code after all, it was something missing in the inspector!